# Seeing open windows via SSH and putty

Tags: ssh, remote, putty, xming

I am currently using my pi2 as a face-recognition log in system, written in python, which is mounted on the wall on the other side of the room.

I am trying to be able to connect to it via putty, over wifi and work with the program remotely.

The pi is connected to a HDMI monitor to display information, however when I log into the pi via putty and run "STARTLXDE" a blank desktop loads, with no processes running. I assume this is a completely different X GUI accessing the file system, then the one that normally runs on the pi (with startx).

My question is: How can I remote to the normal desktop that is running my script over WiFi, preferably via putty and ssh (As I want to avoid tightVNC, so please don't suggest it)

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I don't know if this is important but (more information > less information)..

I am using Raspbian and the desktop that comes up in xming looks suspiciously like NOOBS.

I am using X11 port forwarding

Comment: LXDE is the default desktop on Raspbian, so I suspect these are both it -- just in one case you have a different configuration in play.  I *think* I have seen this issue here before.   You might consider asking about this on [LXDE's](http://lxde.org/) own forum (and if you get an answer there that solves the problem, please post your own here).

Comment: Try running `startx` instead of `STARTLXDE`

Comment: I did try startx instead, and it threw a load of error messages and no window appeared.

Answer (score 1):

You should start `ssh` with X11 forwarding. Look at [this answer in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745963) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am already using port forwarding, I will update my question to include this info

Comment: Did you read the answer from the link? What's the detailed problem?

Comment: Apologies, I read the top answer that was "ticked" as solving the problem, not the second answer. I will give that a try now and report back

Comment: After attemping that, apparently my DISPLAY variable is not set, I fear this might be because I have only installed Xephyr on the pi, and I am trying to access it from a windows machine, the answer linked I think is from linux, can you use this method from windows?